# Is it possible to write string array literals in Android XML resource files?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-preferences

For my PreferenceActivity, I am using the typical preferences.xml file.

The entryValues of a ListPreference is not something meant to be localized. Is it possible to define the entryValues attribute directly using  some kind of array literal?

My first try below won't work, "pull, push" is considered a string:

```
<ListPreference
        android:key="server_reception_mode"
        android:title="@string/title_server_reception_mode_preference"
        android:entries="@array/entries_server_reception_mode_preference"
        android:entryValues="pull, push" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html#attr_android%3aentryValues) for the `entryValues` attribute, no:

> Must be a reference to another resource [...]

Of course, just because you have a string resource doesn't mean you *have* to localise it.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a `<string-array>` array of strings. For example:

```
<string-array name="entry_values">
    <item>pull</item>
    <item>push</item>
</string-array>
```

You could then use it in XML:

```
<ListPreference
    android:key="server_reception_mode"
    android:title="@string/title_server_reception_mode_preference"
    android:entries="@array/entries_server_reception_mode_preference"
    android:entryValues="@array/entry_values" />
```

If all you're after is avoiding translation, you can use the convention used in the [Android sources](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/values): they have resource files named `values/donottranslate.xml`, `values/donottranslate-names.xml`, etc.

Comment: Ernesto was asking whether declaring a string-array is avoidable in the first place, as I understood the question.

Comment: @slyfox - I didn't understand the question that way, but on second reading, I think you're right. I amended my answer to address that.

Comment: @slyfox - You are right, I was asking about fully avoiding the string-array.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an array in your resources. You can't declare it directly like you were hoping to.

For those kind of arrays, I usually create a second XML file with all entries that do not need to be translated (like array-notranslate.xml). That way, if you hand your xml files to somebody for translation, they won't have to deal with it.